# Sorting in SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a database and I want to sort it. I came across several code that selects a sorted data but does not modify the database in itself. 
I came across..
 
So how do I sort a database?

Comment: Why do you need to store it sorted?  you can easily order by any column when you select the data.

Comment: my app works better when its sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean by 'sort a database' to simple sort a table,

1. Create temp table as sorted select, eg you have unsorted `table1` a you want to sort it by `column1` then do this:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE temp_table1 
   AS SELECT * 
   FROM table1 
   ORDER BY column1;
   ```
2. Drop the original table.
3. Rename `temp_table1` to `table1`.

Comment: While this answer is correct AFAIK, and while this might be obvious to some, I would add that the ordering is subject to being broken as soon as an `insert` or an `update` is executed against the table.

Answer (score 2):

You don't sort tables in relational database.

You create index on them. And use ORDER BY in your query. That way your query result will be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

When creating database create index on column to have better query performance:

`CREATE INDEX sorted_idx ON table_name(indexed_column ASC);`

more about indexes:
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html

Then in code select using `ORDER BY`

`db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY indexed_column ASC", null);`